# What's the genre of the music having a breathy female vocals in the background?

Tags: soundtrack, identify-this-genre

I am listening to a music compilation titled *Total War: Rome 2 OST - Campaign Compilation*. This is composed by Richard Beddow and performed either by the Prague Philharmonic or Slovak National Orchestra, as per the details in the video description. The track starting at [3:58](https://youtu.be/9CGtlaKWk8Y?t=238) mins has a humming female voice alongside some stringed and woodwind instruments.

Is there a genre of this type of music (containing such humming vocals), and if so, what is it called?

Comment: Where do you hear humming?

Comment: Such tracks are commonly called ambient, atmospheric.

Answer (score 2):

There's quite a lot of wordless female voice in the track, but I don't hear any humming.
The music doesn't really fit any genre, it's written to evoke a kind of general 'ethnic' feeling without actually copying a specific style. As is typical for this kind of background music, it tries to evoke an atmosphere without drawing attention to itself. So it's probably best described as "pseudo-ethnic film music"

Comment: I concur with PiedPiper's answer but wanted to add:  the [Mongolian musical genre "long song"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_song) happens to share a few attributes with this style of music.  It's a really neat genre, worth looking into.  An example, with some commentary:  https://youtu.be/15kVupa7vVk